# How to make sure two select menu values are not the same with jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, select-menu

I have two different select menus (menu A and menu B). Both with the same values. How do I make sure selected menu A value is not equal to menu B value onsubmit? Would be cool if the selected menu A becomes non selectable on menu B?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to diable the option in the second select

```
$('.select1').on('change',function(){
 var optionInSelect2 = $('.select2').find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
 if(optionInSelect2.length) {
   optionInSelect2.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uz2g6r54/)

Comment: sory about that just remove the quotes from $('this'), updated my answer

Comment: yes I already removed the quotes, still the option of the .select2 menu is still selectable. Could this part of the code be rewritten in an other  way 'find('option[value='+$(this).val()+']')'

Comment: yes, but what if I have say 4 option and I made a mistake by and I select another number in the first menu. Than the option is still disable in the second menu see my update version of your demo
https://jsfiddle.net/uz2g6r54/1/

So how can remove all disabled attributes on menu 2?

Comment: user `removeAttr()`

Comment: I am using this but I can't get it to work with reselecting behavior
`$('.selectA').on('change', function() {
        //$('.selectA [value!="' + $(this).val() + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
//        $('.selectA.removeAttribute('disabled');
//        $('.selectA').find('option').pop('disabled', false);
        $('.selectA [value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        
    });`

Comment: your solution only works with numbers as values, see https://jsfiddle.net/uz2g6r54/5/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest vay to check it on submit is:

```
$("#list1").val() !== $("#list2").val();
```

And if you want to make it non selectable you could something like this:

```
$("#list1").change(function(){

    $("#list2 [value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");

})
```

To erase previous disabled options:

```
$("#list1").change(function(){

    $("#list2").find("option").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $("#list2 [value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");

})
```

Comment: Ok found a workable solution. I had to change some single / double quotes $('.seminarA').on('change',function(){
   
  //
    $('.seminarB [value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
  //
  
});`

Comment: I do have a followup question. While playing with select and deselect I notice the attribute disabled still exists for those options I previously selected. How can I make sure just one option can be disabled?
Something like if elementID option value != $(this).val() $("#elementID").removeAttr('disabled');