# How to prevent same option value from being selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im trying to disabled same option value with the same value from being selected, I am using the same option html id/class which is I found several solution using two different option value.

[How to make sure two select menu values are not the same with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783211/how-to-make-sure-two-select-menu-values-are-not-the-same-with-jquery)

Above solution works perfectly but I couldnt figure out if its using the same option value id/class

below are my code

PHP

```
<?php
$locationnow = $class->locationnow($con);
if(mysqli_num_rows($locationnow)){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($locationnow)){
  $selectlist .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location_name_en'].'</option>';
 }
}
?>
```

//HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="location_id" name="location_id[0]">
  <?php echo $selectlist; ?>
</option>
```

`<button class="btn-sm btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addLocation()" >Add</button>`

//JQUERY
    THIS TO ADD ANOTHER LOCATION

```
var loc = 0;

function addLocation(){

    var html = '';

    loc += 1;

    var numDisplay = loc+1;

    html += '<div class="form-group">';

    html += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"onclick="$(this).closest(\'.form-group\').remove()" type=button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>&nbsp;';

    html += '<label for="location_id">Location '+numDisplay+'</label>';

    html += '<select class="form-control" name="location_id['+loc+']" id="location_id">';

    html += '<?php echo $selectlist; ?>';

    html += '</select>';

    html += '</div>';

    $('.locationRows').append(html);


}

//THIS IS TO REMOVE DUPLICATE
$('#location_id').on('change',function(){
var optionInSelect2 = $('#location_id').find('option[value!="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
 if(optionInSelect2.length) {
   optionInSelect2.attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: i suggest to fix the query not to return same values . maybe distinct can help

Comment: Do you mean you have two `<select>` tags with same set of options, and you don't want your user to be able to select the same value for two `<select>` element? Or you just have one `<select>` tag that having options with same value?

Comment: @SolomonTam using same select, I add another location using the jquery to trigger the html, but both using same class and id name, let edit my my questiion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, avoid using same `id` in html since `$("#location_id")` will only select one element even there is two.

In this case, I use `$("select[name^='location_id']")` to select the `<select>` element by JQuery.

I implement following function for handling options disabled.

```
function updateSelect(){
    var selectedValue = [];
    $("select[name^='location_id']").each(function(index, element){
        var value = $(element).val();
        if(value.length > 0){
            selectedValue.push(value);
        }
    });

    $("select[name^='location_id'] option").attr("disabled", false);
    $("select[name^='location_id'] option").not(":selected").each(function(index, element){
        if(selectedValue.indexOf($(element).val()) !== -1){
            $(element).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

And since your `<select>` element is created dynamically, add event listener to `$('#location_id')` won't work on all element. You need to add event listener to body with passing selector as parameters.

```
$("body").on("change", "select[name^='location_id']", function(e){
    updateSelect();
});
```

Also, when you add new element or remove select, you need to invoke `updateSelect()`, so that when element is added/deleted, other elements will update the disabled attribute.

The following shows a working exmaple without PHP. (I replace your PHP output with some dummy options)

```js
  var loc = 0;

  function updateSelect() {
    var selectedValue = [];
    $("select[name^='location_id']").each(function(index, element) {
      var value = $(element).val();
      if (value.length > 0) {
        selectedValue.push(value);
      }
    });

    $("select[name^='location_id'] option").attr("disabled", false);
    $("select[name^='location_id'] option").not(":selected").each(function(index, element) {
      if (selectedValue.indexOf($(element).val()) !== -1) {
        $(element).attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  }

  function addLocation() {

    var html = '';

    loc += 1;

    var numDisplay = loc + 1;

    html += '<div class="form-group">';

    html += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"onclick="$(this).closest(\'.form-group\').remove();updateSelect();" type=button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>&nbsp;';

    html += '<label for="location_id">Location ' + numDisplay + '</label>';

    html += '<select class="form-control" name="location_id[' + loc + ']" id="location_id">';

    html += '<option value="">---Please Select---</option><option value="1">Location A</option><option value="2">Location B</option><option value="3">Location C</option>';

    html += '</select>';

    html += '</div>';

    $('.locationRows').append(html);

    updateSelect();

  }

  $("body").on("change", "select[name^='location_id']", function(e) {
    updateSelect();
  });
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="location_id" name="location_id[0]">
  <option value="">---Please Select---</option>
  <option value="1">Location A</option>
  <option value="2">Location B</option>
  <option value="3">Location C</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-sm btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addLocation()">Add</button>

<div class="locationRows"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great explanation and accurate answer, Ill take the eplanation for future references, thanks